# Accessing a static method from different threads

Tags: c#, static

Imagine a static method called foo() that is taking a considerable amount of time to execute. This method is inside a static class.

```
public static class FooClass
{
   public static void Foo()
   {
      Thread.Sleep(120000); // 2 minutes.
   }
}
```

I have a two instances of the same class that are calling this method concurrently. Since the `FooClass` is static, does that mean that *Instance2* has to wait for *Instance1* to finish executing `foo()` (given that *Instance1* entered `foo()` first)?

From my knowledge, static classes contains one instance that is shared across the application pool.

Comment: You are mixing up static classes and static methods. Also, your code doesn't compile as you have non-static method in static class.

Comment: @Euphoric, can you please elaborate why I am mixing up static classes and static methods?

Comment: @kidra.pazzo - Dmitry fixed it for you but you had `public void Foo()` instead of `public static void Foo()` which would not compile as `FooClass` was marked as static.

Comment: Ah my apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not have to wait. Both threads can enter `Foo` at the same time and in the code above each thread will sleep for 2 minutes.

The only way to make one thread wait on another is to add a synchronization / locking mechanism like the `lock` keyword, or tyes `Mutex` or `Monitor` (to name a few).

Comment: Is it because the methods are reentrant?

Comment: @kidra.pazzo - No. The same is true of an instance method, they could also be accessed simultaneously by multiple threads. Threads and instance/static members have no direct relation to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The same method can run on two threads at the 'same time', so both threads will sleep. If you need to ensure the method is atomic for each call (if it was editing data) you need to use a lock.